# Symfony error with form entity class

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to add some validation rules for my form by using callbacks for a few choice fields.
This callback I saw in the documentation should be in the entity class for that form. But in my case I'm having all the time this problem:

"ContextErrorException: Notice: Array to string conversion in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/bbc/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/ChoiceList/ChoiceList.php line 462"

My code in my entity looks like this:

```
namespace Cgboard\AppBundle\Forms;

use Cgboard\AppBundle\Classes\Iplayer;

class SearchEntity
{
    public $category;
    public $coming_soon_within;
    public $local_radio;
    public $masterbrand;
    public $max_tleos;
    public $media_set;
    public $page;
    public $perPage;
    public $q;
    public $search_availibity;
    public $service_type;
    public $signed;


    public static function getCategories()  // all this getters are firing the error, why?
    {
        return ['undef',
                'arts',
                'cbcc',
                'comedy'];
    }

    public static function getLocalRadio()
    { 
     ......
```

I want to use these callbacks from my validation.yml file, that looks like this one:

```
Cgboard\AppBundle\Forms\SearchEntity:
  properties:
    category:
      - Choice: { callback: getCategories }
    coming_soon_within:
      - Range:
          min: 1
          max: 168
    local_radio:
      - Choice: { callback: getLocalRadio }
    masterbrand:
      - Choice: { callback: getMasterbrand }
    ....
```

Even if I delete the whole content from validation.yml I still have the error. So I think the problem is just with the entity form class. Any idea about how to work around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Because I think can be handy for someone else. The problem was that I was using getters (getLocalRadio for instance) that were creating conflicts for the internal getters used by SYmfony. I just changed the name of these getter and everything worked fine